# How do I use a custom 503 error page with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have implemented rate limiting with Nginx (which works excellently, by the way) and would like to display a custom 503 error page.

I have followed examples on the web without luck.

I am running a simple configuration that looks something like this:

```
listen x.x.x.x:80
server_name something.com
root /usr/local/www/something.com;
error_page 503 /503.html;

location / {
  limit_req zone=default burst=5 nodelay;
  proxy_pass http://mybackend;
}
```

The idea is that our rate limited users would be shown a special page explaining what was going on.  The rate limiting is working, but the built-in 503 page is rendering.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add

```
location = /503.html {
  root /path/to/the/page;
}
```